# How to change date-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following HTML but I am not able to change the value of date-value and title. Can you please suggest how to do this?

```
<a title="Date::04/08/2013">
  <span class="name">Date::</span>
  <span data-value="04/08/2013" class="value">04/16/2013</span>
</a>
```

Sorry for the incomplete question.

Value 04/16/2013 is assigned using jQuery but the title="Date::04/08/2013" and data-value="04/08/2013" doesn't changed. I want `"Date::04/08/2013"` should be `"Date::04/16/2013"` and `data-value="04/08/2013"` should be `data-value="04/16/2013"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no `date-value` as mentioned twice in text... there is `data-value` however. Is this the root of your problem? WHat have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this

```
<a title="Date::04/08/2013" id='date-link'>
  <span id="date-title" class="name">Date::</span>
  <span id="date-value" data-value="04/08/2013" class="value">04/16/2013</span>
</a>
```

and you want following

```
<a title="Date::04/16/2013" id='date-link'>
  <span id="date-title" class="name">Date::</span>
  <span id="date-value" data-value="04/16/2013" class="value">04/16/2013</span>
</a>
```

If so, you can try following

```
var dateTitle = jQuery("#date-title").html()
var dateValue = jQuery("#date-value").html()
jQuery('#date-link').attr('title', dateTitle+dateValue);
jQuery('#date-value').attr('data-value', dateValue);
```

You can create a html file with following code and check your own

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a title="Date::04/08/2013" id='date-link'>
  <span id="date-title" class="name">Date::</span>
  <span id="date-value" data-value="04/08/2013" class="value">04/16/2013</span>
</a>

<a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick="abc()">Click Here</a>

<script>
    function abc() {
    var dateTitle = jQuery("#date-title").html()
    var dateValue = jQuery("#date-value").html()
    jQuery('#date-link').attr('title', dateTitle+dateValue);
    jQuery('#date-value').attr('data-value', dateValue);}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('span.value').attr("data-value", "04/16/2013")
```

`.data("value")` might not work, since **value** maps to something else.

Besides, try using some other keyword other than **value**, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.value').attr('data-value',$('.value').html());
```

Comment: `this` is `window` in your solution and not the element... won't work as shown.

Comment: if `this` doesn't work... then change it to you identifier, in this case `.value`

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('.value').text();
$('.value').attr('data-value',value)
```

Answer (score 0):

**html code:**

```
<a title="Date" id="data">
  <span class="name">Date::</span>
  <span data-value="04/08/2013" class="value">04/16/2013</span>
</a>
```

**js:**

```
$("#data").find('span').attr("data-value", "04/16/2013");
```

try this u ll get data-value...